# Sunny Studios goes bankrupt! - How to cancel a project in Game Dev Story

Tags: game-dev-story

I've reached the point in Game Dev Story that I'm just beginning work on my first console! However, after a few months developing, I see that I've made a grave mistake... I'm a few $100k short of meeting payroll come the end of March. Unfortunately reloading an early save isn't an option as my manual save is a few months into development. I tried boosting through development, but I just can't boost fast enough. At this point my only option, as far as I can see, is to cancel the project. However, I can't quite see how to do this.

How do I cancel a project in progress?

Comment: I read somewhere that "going in to the red" doesn't end the game, but just means you can't start new projects. So maybe you'll be OK if you can finish the console and start selling it?

Comment: @Jwaddell This is good news to hear. I guess that's the route to go then. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** The below instructions are for games. It is not possible to cancel a console.

Tap the bar with the stats. You are shown a screen with two option "Ship" which will not work at this point (only works for games in the debugging stage) and "Cancel". Tap the Cancel option.

Comment: When I do this, all I get is a pop-up that says "Now developing a console".

Comment: @Aeo: My bad. That is how you cancel projects in Game Dev Story. If it doesn't work for consoles, that means you cannot cancel consoles.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate... Guess I'll have to just play it out and see what happens then. Maybe they'll let me go into debt till after console launch.

Comment: Note that if your console is decent other companies will develop for it as well and you'll get license money as well as sales.

Comment: I was millions in debt after I got into the final office. The best thing to do it quickly crank out as many projects as possible and just hope the console sales + current game sales will pull you out of recession. It took me almost four years.